# gdbserver remote target: Target description specified unknown architecture "arm" Where is gdb binary for ARMv7?

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, gdb, remote-debugging

I have a target machine, raspberry pi ARMv7, that I want to debug remotely from my windows machine.

I want to use gdb gdbserver with 'target remote' to debug the docker container remotely.

My executable is compiled c++ src code.

**Dockerfile** that I run on raspberry pi

```
FROM arm32v7/ubuntu:latest

# Install necessary packages and cross-compiling toolchain
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdb gdbserver g++ bash
RUN apt-get install -y crossbuild-essential-armhf gdb-multiarch
ENV CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
ENV CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
ENV AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar

# Copy the source code
COPY . /app

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Compile the source code
RUN ${CXX} -g -o testapp2 testapp2.cpp

# Run the executable
CMD ["./testapp2"]
```

I believe my windows machine needs a pre-built binary of gdb for the ARMv7 architecture.

I looked through linaro.org and developer.arm.com but I haven't been able to find a download for this.

Do I need to build it myself on my windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully `target remote` by using

`gdb-multiarch -ex "target remote Enter-Ip-Address-Here:Enter-TCP-Port-Here" /path/to/executable/in/the/docker/container/here`

in Windows Subsystem Linux